Recommendations for cases with multiple CD/DVD slots
Not sure if it's the right place. I'm looking for a case that will have place for:

2 CD/DVD drives,
1 floppy drive (3.5", 1.44mb)

I am not looking for a sleeper's build. Just a modern/semi-modern looking case, with front space for these 3 drives.
I saw several which had space for 2 CD/DVD drives, but not for three.

Can I ask what you're using multiple DVD drives for? I personally use Blue-rays for archival storage, but the consensus among most is that optical media is dead.

Cooler Master N400 - $77

I'm not aware of many modern cases that fit the bill, particularly the 3.5" drive bay, since those have been virtually entirely forsaken since floppies fell out of popularity. Of the new cases that remain on the market, the venerable Cooler Master N400 is probably your best bet. It's not an amazing case by "modern" standards, and it's been on the market for about a decade at this point, but it's serviceable and fits your requirements.
That said, I'd also encourage you to look into one of the following options:
Phanteks Enthoo Pro with a 5.25" to 3.5" adapter - $110 + $9

Admittedly, the Enthoo Pro is a substantially more expensive case. However, I'd argue it's justified given the additional flexibility offered by the additional 5.25" bay—not to mention the additional drive capacity, tempered glass window, better cable management options, PSU cover, and general ergonomic improvements of a substantially more modern design.
Some used case - $?
I know you're not looking for a sleeper build, but there are tons and tons of relatively modern but no longer manufactured cases that would fit your bill. Take for example the Corsair 750D and 800D: plenty of drive bays, and due to the former popularity, often available for reasonable prices second hand. They look pretty modern, and have solid features. While it's obviously difficult to make a specific recommendation due to variable availability and pricing on local markets, there's plenty of options out there.
